# run rsync once new file appears in specific folder

Tags: windows-10, backup, python, rsync

I'm looking for a piece of software that would run rsync automatically once a new file appears in a certain folder. I tried programming it myself with python but that turned out to be harder than I thought It'd be, so I'm looking for software that can do that. It should run on windows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use lsyncd for that.

https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd

It is available as deb/rpm on both CentOS/RedHat and Debian/Ubuntu platforms.

EDIT:
Didn't see the question was for Windows, check [Live rsync/directory monitor for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/347456/live-rsync-directory-monitor-for-windows) for possible solutions

Comment: does it work with windows?

Comment: sorry, didn't see you meant windows, check https://superuser.com/questions/347456/live-rsync-directory-monitor-for-windows, also if you have windows 10 you can try installing ubuntu for windows, linux bash that windows 10 offers, it has lsyncd, but not sure if it works as intended on linux